# SQLite Like versus Substr

Tags: sqlite, substr, sql-like

I want to compare the last 4 characters of a Text field.

Performance wise, should I do:

```
select * from table where col like '%last';
```

OR

```
select * from table where substr(col,-4)='last';
```

Comment: Another consideration: `LIKE` is SQL92 standard, I'm not so sure about `SUBSTR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using `EXPLAIN` before the queries, to see the virtual machine operations, and the one with the `substr()` function had 3 more OP codes than the one with `LIKE`. That doesn't mean it is necessarily slower, but is an indication it might be.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to take advantage of an index when using the ends-with wildcard:

```
          LIKE '%.edu'
```

An alternative would be to store a reversed version of the string in another column, index that reverse-content column, and then use LIKE (or better, the GLOB function [*because in several SQLite implementations LIKE() has been overridden, which also prevents index  use*] passing a reversed version of the string you're looking for. For example, if you were looking for URLs that ended with .edu you would search the reversed-column for values starting-with 'ude.'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which has the better performance, but the first one is much better to read and I would not expect any significant differences in performance.

Answer (score 1):

[The optimizer overview](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) page, section 4, explains that the LIKE operator is designed to optimize expressions of the kind `col LIKE 'something that does not begin with a percent sign%'`.